# What does echo $((2#$1)) exactly does?

Tags: bash

The following bash script displays a decimal number when given binary number.

```
echo $((2#$1))
```

Why exactly ?

I understand that `$1` is the input. Maybe `2` is the base (binary). But I can't understand the syntax used.

Comment: if you understood that $1 was a positional parameter then you should have simplified your question and done just `echo $((2#0110))` as you did and got '6'. Then you ask if 2 was the base. Well obviously. And it's not hard to test that. It's no coincidence that `echo $((2#0111))`  is 7.  and  $((2#1000))` is 8. You got it for one binary number. So  given that, then yeah you got it anyway , obviously

Comment: @barlop I recently edited the question to add the `echo $((2#0110)) = 6` part, because I noticed there was no direct example with output in my question and in the answers

Comment: Kind of makes a nonsense of the question ('cos if a questioner knew that then they'd know the answer).  Though as you know an example is good.     It's one of those things where if you'd been careful about asking the question properly in the first place before posting it, so before clicking "submit/post",  then you would have ended up solving it yourself easily.  Sometimes I start asking a question and i've typed it and refined it but I solve it in the process of asking a good question, so nothing to ask.   Other times I solve the question but it's a good question so I post both Q and A.

Comment: this one wasn't a well written question, because you just posted it without doing any troubleshooting

Comment: @barlop well thank you for your opinion, it is very interesting. other users seem to have had another one

Comment: @barlop your first remark is right tho, I added the example to the accepted answer instead of my original question

Answer (score 76, accepted):

man bash

```
   echo [-neE] [arg ...]
          Output  the  args,  separated  by spaces, followed by a newline.
          The return status is 0 unless a write error occurs.   If  -n  is
          specified, the trailing newline is suppressed.  If the -e option
          is given,  interpretation  of  the  following  backslash-escaped
          characters  is  enabled.
```

[...]

```
   Arithmetic Expansion
       Arithmetic  expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression
       and the substitution of the result.  The format for  arithmetic  expan‐
       sion is:

              $((expression))
```

[...]

```
   Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.  A leading
   0x or  0X  denotes  hexadecimal.   Otherwise,  numbers  take  the  form
   [base#]n,  where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64
   representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that  base.   If
   base#  is omitted, then base 10 is used.  When specifying n, the digits
   greater than 9 are represented by the lowercase letters, the  uppercase
   letters, @, and _, in that order.  If base is less than or equal to 36,
   lowercase and uppercase letters may be used interchangeably  to  repre‐
   sent numbers between 10 and 35.
```

Comment: -1 for ZERO explanation.

Comment: It is pretty well explained I think

Comment: Fully answering a question, even if "only" by curating existing documentation, does not deserve -1 for me. In particular if that documentation is the manpage of bash.

Comment: I didn't vote, but, IMHO, quoting the explanation of the `echo` command was unnecessary.

Comment: `man bash | wc` indicates the [GNU bash, version 3.2.57] man page to be 4890 lines, **37094 words**, 329778 characters. This answer strips that down to only the 7 lines, **176 words**, 1115 characters that are relevant. I think that answer deserves your upvote. (as does this comment ;-)

Comment: @BrunoBronosky dunno you, but my pager have search on the / key.

Comment: @Braiam, yes and `/2#` gives 0 results, but seriously this is not a place for debate and 1337ism. My comment was intended to encourage community not exacerbate division. There is an important cultural difference between SE and Reddit/4chan/etc.

Comment: @Braiam - I gave up on the pager a long time ago. I do a `man bash > bashman.txt`, make it read only and throw it into kate. I just have to remember to get a new version every so often. It's nice to have a script on one tab and the manual on another. I do the same thing for awk and yad.

Comment: @MaxRied: -1 to your comment for seeking unnecessary fluff

Comment: @Joe You can do `man bash | kate -i` if you're not worried about the filename. Or `man bash | gedit -` for folk who use gedit. Note the dash on the end.

Comment: @seumasmac - I was wondering what that `-i` option was good for. Thanks.

Comment: @MaxRied What nonsense. You're the one who's rigidly copying something without any flexibility here. In general those answers which just copy things are bad because they confuse the readers since they're not directly relevant/applicable to the question. But here the relevant explanations are all here. It's just that they come from the source instead of being rephrased. If something is already clear enough, why would you rephrase? It would just be an absolute waste of effort anyways.

Answer (score 31):

From the Doc at: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers. A leading ‘0x’ or ‘0X’ denotes hexadecimal. Otherwise, numbers take the form [base#]n, where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base. If base# is omitted, then base 10 is used. When specifying n, the digits greater than 9 are represented by the lowercase letters, the uppercase letters, ‘@’, and ‘_’, in that order. If base is less than or equal to 36, lowercase and uppercase letters may be used interchangeably to represent numbers between 10 and 35.

So `echo $((16#FF))` outputs `255` and `echo $((2#0110))` outputs `6`

Answer (score 26):

[Ipor's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1162557/23156) is excellent but very slightly incomplete. The quoted part of the bash man page states that the `[base#]n` syntax works only for constants, and `2#$1` is not a constant. You should be asking how this *really* works!

> EXPANSION
>
>   Expansion is performed on the command line
>     after it has been split into words. 
>     There are seven kinds of expansion performed: brace expansion,
>     tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion,
>     command substitution,
>     arithmetic expansion,
>     word splitting, and pathname expansion.
>
> The  order of expansions is: brace expansion;
>   tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion,
>   arithmetic expansion,
>   and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion);
>   word splitting; and pathname expansion.

Basically Bash is doing variable substitution first, so that the `$1` is first replaced with its value. Only then does it do arithmetic expansion, which sees only a proper constant.

Comment: This seems unnecessary; the OP says, "I understand that `$1` is the input."

Comment: +1 because understanding the order of expansion is very useful for making sense of many different Bash expressions.

Comment: This could have simply been a comment to Ipor's answer.

Comment: @chepner Please try to squeeze that well-formatted blockquote into a comment :-)

Comment: "Note that the parameter `$1` is expanded to produce an integer constant before the arithmetic expression is evaluated. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.txt, section 3.5"